# Magento Custom PDF Invoice Module

Tags: magento, pdf, invoices

I try to make simply pdf invoice:

```
class KM_PdfInvoice_Model_Sales_Order_Pdf_Invoice extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice
```

Already have designed skelet layout for PDF. But now my problem is access ordes data like:

Ordered items, customer name, shiping, billing adress, etc..
When you press button submit:
[image]

or press button print:
[image]

getPdf() is going exected:

```
public function getPdf($invoices = array()){


    foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
        if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
            Mage::app()->getLocale()->emulate($invoice->getStoreId());
            Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($invoice->getStoreId());
        }

        $OrderId    =   Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(self::XML_PATH_SALES_PDF_INVOICE_PUT_ORDER_ID);
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($OrderId);

        // echo $OrderId;

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($order);
        echo '</pre>';
```

But **$OrderId** don't want work, so i can't start access order details.
I need give **order id** to getPdf();
What I'm doing wrong?

P.S My config.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <KM_PdfInvoice>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
        </KM_PdfInvoice>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <order_pdf_invoice>KM_PdfInvoice_Model_Sales_Order_Pdf_Invoice</order_pdf_invoice>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
        </models>     
    </global>  
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

To Access $order just need call:

```
            $order = $invoice->getOrder();
```